# Path relater errors on compilation in Arduino IDE 1.8.5 under Windows XP

Tags: compilation-errors

For the XP under the Russian locale I'm getting the strange output when trying to compile Marlin project for Anycoubic 3d printer according to instruction https://3dtoday.ru/blogs/trialon/marlin119-for-anycubic-kossel-linear-plus

avr-g++: error: C:\DOCUME~1\ИЖИ: No such file or directory

avr-g++: error: Ь~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\arduino_build_153827\sketch\Marlin.ino.cpp: No such file or directory

avr-g++: error: Ь~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\arduino_build_153827\preproc\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp: No such file or directory

avr-g++: warning: '-x c++' after last input file has no effect

avr-g++: fatal error: no input files

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Ошибка компиляции для платы Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560.

Answer (score 2):

I have realized that the root cause was the windows user with the Cyrillic name. So creating a new user wiht base Latin name and running Arduino IDE from it helped